# SPARQL query - Class and subclass give a class name and namespace

Tags: rdf, semantic-web, sparql, owl, ontology

How can i get all the class properties and its sub classes with properties from an RDF datasource using SPARQL query given a class name and namespace?

Comment: When you say you want the "class properties" do you mean individuals (instances of a class) and their properties? When you want subclasses, do you want transitive subclasses as well (A => B, B => C, so you want A => C)? Can you provide an example of the RDF graph you're querying?

Answer (score 4):

Are you trying to do a recursive SPARQL query? In other words, select a given individual and all of it's properties. Where the object of the property is another individual, select its properties, and so on.

I don't believe SPARQL supports this.

The naive approach would be to do something like this (and, assuming you mean individuals and not classes, this actually matches your requirements but doesn't handle the next "level" of triples).

```
CONSTRUCT {
    ?s ?p ?o .
    ?o ?p2 ?o2 .
} WHERE {
    ?s ?p ?o .
    ?o ?p2 ?o2 .
}
```

Note that if `?o2` is the subjects of any statements, this query will not return them.

Answer (score 3):

How about [this](http://dbpedia.org/snorql/?query=%0D%0ASELECT+%3FsubClass%2C+%3Fpredicate+%0D%0AWHERE+%7B%0D%0A+++%3FsubClass+rdfs%3AsubClassOf+%3Chttp%3A%2F%2Fdbpedia.org%2Fontology%2FWork%3E+.%0D%0A+++%3Fpredicate+rdfs%3Adomain+%3FsubClass%0D%0A%7D):

```
PREFIX rdfs: <http://www.w3.org/2000/01/rdf-schema#>
SELECT ?subClass ?predicate 
WHERE {
   ?subClass rdfs:subClassOf <http://dbpedia.org/ontology/Work> .
   ?predicate rdfs:domain ?subClass
}
```

Give it a try on a SPARQL tool such as [DBPedia's SNORQL interface](http://dbpedia.org/snorql/).